# Chef: Running chef-client during knife upload / knife role from file

Tags: chef-infra

What happens if during a `chef-client` run someone is altering the chef server using `knife upload cookbooks`, `knife environment from file...` or `knife role from file` ? Is it possible that the node will remain in an uncertain state if these commands are being run sequently and the `chef-client` is being executed in between ? Or does the Chef server have any lock mechanism that prevents this issue ?

Thanks in advance,
Antonio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no locking system, the last writer will win. The state is never uncertain per se, but it can be confusing to the end user(s). This is especially notable with node edits, since a running chef-client keeps a copy of the node data for the duration of the run, potentially overwriting server-side changes made to the node while it was converging. As such, we do not recommend editing nodes unless you are certain there is no running chef-client process on it.

Comment: Thank you! We always sync our chef git repo with the chef server on every push to the master branch. The nodes are running every 15 minutes chef-client , would you recommend implementing our own lock, that would prevent nodes from executing if the chef server is receiving updates ?

Comment: Just to clarify - we are not editing the nodes only modifying cookbooks, roles and data bags

Comment: No, that's fine. The node only writes to itself. You might some day get a  weird transient error if `chef-client` happens to run at exactly the wrong moment between cookbook uploads or something but we all just live with it, it's so rare as to not be worth worrying about.

Comment: It does mean that you shouldn't have people manually uploading roles or cookbooks though, since those could do weird things if it happens during a sync.